# C# delete file after using

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a file in C# after doing some work upon it, but its not working as giving an error like another process is using the file, how can i do that thing any one please have any idea?

Comment: You need to show some code of how you are currently trying to do this if we can try to assist

Comment: Show some code pls. I guess it must be you forget to close file after write :)

Comment: as curtisk said need to show some code to understand the issue. on the other hand if you are opening the file from C# code to do processing, then you need to close it before trying to delete it.

Comment: you mention you are trying to delete it after using it. Are you sure you closed the file after using it? If not, you won't be able to delete it since you still have it open.

Answer (score 8):

You make sure you close the file after you're done working with it.  If another process has it open then track the handle to see what is going on (Process Explorer is good for this).

If you wrap your file open in a `using` statement this happens for you at the end of the block.  Otherwise make sure to call `Dispose()` on the stream before opening it again.

```
using(var fs = File.Open(path))
using(var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    // do stuff with the file
}   // Dispose() is called here which closes the file as well

try
{
    // should work now
    File.Delete(path);
}
catch(SomeException ex)
{
    // just in case, do something
}
```

Comment: +1, my money's on the file being left unclosed by the same process immediately prior to deletion.

Comment: @user1175196: I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

I am using code like

```
        DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\TimeQImages\");
        if (DI.Exists)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            FileInfo[] fi = DI.GetFiles();
            int size = fi.Length;
            if (size < 100)
            {
                size = 100 / size;
            }
            else
            {
                size = (int)(size / 100);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo f in fi)
            {
                progressBar1.Value += size;
                ConvertToChunks(f.FullName);                     
                f.Delete();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Transfer completed");
        }
```

Here i am not getting any dispose function on file info

Comment: No, FileInfo does not implement IDisposable. Show us your `ConvertToChunks` function and add this to your original post instead of an answer.

Comment: What are you doing in the ConvertToChunks method? Like a lot of people have pointed out: chances are you're not closing the file in that call