# How to delete a file that is still being downloading using stream?

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is when the user clicks the red X button on the form1 top right corner while a file is downloading.

in that case I'm getting this exception:

The process cannot access the file 'D:\New folder (76)\100MB' because it is being used by another process

this is a helper method to close the file stream before deleting it.
but when I'm using a breakpoint the code never reach the line:

```
fileStream.Close();
```

the does reaching the line:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(downloadFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

but never pass it in and "jump" to the catch and show the exception.

```
private void CloseFileStream()
{
    // Close the file stream if it's still open
    if (downloadFilePath != null && File.Exists(downloadFilePath))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(downloadFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                // Add your logic here to properly close the file stream if needed
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions or log them as needed
            Console.WriteLine($"Error closing file stream: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

this method download a file and if the user cancel the download it will also call the method CloseFileStream but this time it wil lwork fine:

```
private async Task DownloadFile(string docUrl, string path)
{
    // for the sake of the example, let's add a client definition here
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(docUrl));

    downloadFilePath = filePath;

    // Use Invoke to update the UI with the current download link
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBoxUrl.Text = docUrl;
    });

    // Setup your progress reporters
    var progress = new Progress<float>();
    var speedProgress = new Progress<Tuple<long, TimeSpan>>();
    var sizeProgress = new Progress<long>(); // Added for size progress

    progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;
    sizeProgress.ProgressChanged += SizeProgress_ProgressChanged; // Added event handler

    // Use the provided extension method with CancellationToken
    using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        try
        {
            await client.DownloadDataAsync(docUrl, file, progress, speedProgress, sizeProgress, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure the file stream is closed
            CloseFileStream();

            if (isCancel)
            {
                if (File.Exists(downloadFilePath))
                {
                    // Delete the partially downloaded file
                    File.Delete(downloadFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the second place I'm calling the method is in the OnFormClosed when the user click the red X button on the form1 top right corner:

and this time it's throwing the exception:

```
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosed(e);

    // Your logic here to properly close the file stream if needed
    CloseFileStream();

    // Dispose of resources, cancel any ongoing downloads, etc.
    cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel(); // Cancel any ongoing downloads
    cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose(); // Dispose of the CancellationTokenSource
}
```

the problem is that I can't even first closing the file stream while downloading the file before even trying to delete the file.

Comment: Have a look in this Stack case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170167/c-sharp-delete-file-after-using

Comment: Your file variable inside the download method needs to be a class-level variable/property. In the form close, you are opening an entirely new stream without closing the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the file inside the using statement. It needs to be done outside the using statement. As you se in the link I posted before.